# Fijar valor por default en mat-autocomplete

Tags: angular

Quiero dejar por default el valor de sessionStorage.getItem('sessionname')) en un mat-autocomplete, cada vez que se guarde el valor y refresque la pagina que me aparezca ahi, pero no lo pone, aqui dejo mi codigo.

html

```html
<form class="example-form">
  <mat-form-field>
    <input
      type="text"
      placeholder="select Unit Origin"
      matInput
      [formControl]="myControlUnitOrigin"
      [matAutocomplete]="autoUnitOrigin"      
      maxlength="0"      
      [(ngModel)]="selectedUnitOrigin"     
      [multiple]="false"
    />
    <mat-autocomplete
      #autoUnitOrigin="matAutocomplete"
      [displayWith]="displayFnUnitOrigin"
    >
      <mat-option
        *ngFor="let option of unitOriginList | async"
        (onSelectionChange)="onChangeUnitOrigin(option)"
        [value]="option"
      >
        {{option.name}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

ts

```html
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map, startWith } from 'rxjs/operators';

export interface User {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  code: string;
  unitOriginList: User[];
}

@Component({
  selector: 'autocomplete-display-example',
  templateUrl: 'autocomplete-display-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['autocomplete-display-example.css'],
})
export class AutocompleteDisplayExample implements OnInit {
  code: string = '';
  public isUnitOrigin: boolean = false;
  public receivingDataList = {} as User;
  public myControlUnitOrigin = new FormControl();
  public unitOriginList: Observable<User[]>;
  public selectedUnitOrigin: User;
  public selectedOriginFlag: string = '';

  options: User[] = [
    { id: '0', name: 'Mary', code: 'M', unitOriginList: [] },
    { id: '1', name: 'Shelley', code: 'S', unitOriginList: [] },
    { id: '2', name: 'Jhon', code: 'J', unitOriginList: [] },
  ];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getUnitOrigin();
  }

  getUnitOrigin() {
    this.myControlUnitOrigin.setValue({
      name: sessionStorage.getItem('sessionname'),
    });
    console.log(sessionStorage.getItem('sessionname'));

    this.receivingDataList.unitOriginList = this.options;
    this.unitOriginList = this.myControlUnitOrigin.valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith<string | User>(''),
      map((value) => (typeof value === 'string' ? value : value.code)),
      map((code) =>
        code
          ? this._filterOptionUnitOrigin(code)
          : this.receivingDataList.unitOriginList.slice()
      )
    );
  }

  displayFnUnitOrigin(dropDown: any): string {
    return dropDown && dropDown.name ? dropDown.name : '';
  }

  private _filterOptionUnitOrigin(code: string): any[] {
    const filterValue = code;
    const origin = this.receivingDataList.unitOriginList.find(
      (option, index) => {
        return option.code === filterValue;
      }
    );
    sessionStorage.setItem('sessionname', origin.name);
    return this.receivingDataList.unitOriginList.filter(
      (option) => option.code.toUpperCase().indexOf(filterValue) === 0
    );
  }

  onChangeUnitOrigin(currentValue) {
    this.selectedUnitOrigin = currentValue;
  }
```